# Why does cabal haddock --hyperlink-source not generate the source HTMLs?

Tags: haskell, hyperlink, cabal, haddock

For a cabal project, I wanted to generate haddock documentation with hyperlinks to the source code, so I did the usual:

```sh
cabal haddock --hyperlink-source
```

The links were generated, but upon clicking the links I find that the actual source code is not included even though the links are.  The source code is supposed to be rendered via HTML.  How do I generate those as well?

---

Currently using:

- Cabal 1.22.4.0
- cabal-install 1.22.6.0
- haddock 2.16.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it was because *hscolour* was not installed.  Installing it via:

```sh
cabal install hscolour
```

fixed the problem.

Interestingly, there *was* a warning for it that said

```
Warning: The program 'hscolour' version >=1.8 is required but it could not be found.
```

but it was buried inside the usual haddock output so I didn't notice it until now.